# Prepositions: specifically to, in, for?

Tags: prepositions, commas

What is an appropriate variant to say, for example, "Apples and, specifically to/in/for this articles, red apples are very important"? For a man I'd choose exactly "to", e.g. "specifically to me", but I feel it is not the case for a paper.

In addition, have I put commas correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Apples, and specific to this article, red apples, are very important.
- Apples, and specifically in this article, red apples,....
- Apples, and specifically for this article, red apples....

All three work fine, they have a slightly different emphasis.